# PHP if SteamID is equal to the MYSQL Row

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

It will not work. I'm trying like below.

```
if (($row["steamid"]) == $steamprofile['steamid']){
```

Below is full code snippet.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$eh = $steamprofile[steamid];
$sql = "SELECT steamid FROM Main";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (($row["steamid"]) == $steamprofile['steamid']){
echo "SteamID Is Equal and Created!";
}

    }
} else {
    echo "Nope?";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Ive tried various methods.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Using `==` is correct as it will compare the variables, so the problem is most likely that the variable values are not what you expect them to be. Try echoing them to the browser to debug.

Comment: try echo $row["steamid"]) ."==". $steamprofile['steamid']; so you can print and check that.

Comment: my fear is that that first if condision eats the query

Comment: are you getting `Nope?` output?

Comment: By the way, where is your `$steamprofile` being made?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "stackoverflow");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//assume 1
$steamprofile['steamid']=1;

// changes here single quote    
$eh = $steamprofile['steamid'];

$sql = "SELECT steamid FROM Main";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
        if (($row["steamid"]) == $steamprofile['steamid']){
echo "SteamID Is Equal and Created!";
}

    }
} else {
    echo "Nope?";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

output is
SteamID Is Equal and Created!

Mysql Database------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main` (
`steamid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `main`

INSERT INTO `main` (`steamid`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'test1'),
(2, 'test2');

Answer (score 0):

I think your

```
$eh = $steamprofile[steamid];
```

should be changed to

```
$eh = $steamprofile['steamid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment by:

try echo $row["steamid"]) ."==". $steamprofile['steamid']; so you can print and check that. – Hardy Mathew

Worked. Thanks.